# Remove part of a string based on another column in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, str-replace, gsub

I have a large dataset that looks like this. I want to remove a certain number of strings from the fruits columns indicated by the remove_strings column.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(fruits=c("apple","banana","ananas"), 
             remove_strings=c(1,4,2))

df
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   fruits remove_strings
#>   <chr>           <dbl>
#> 1 apple               1
#> 2 banana              4
#> 3 ananas              2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

From apple I want to remove the first string, from banana the first 4 and ananas the first 2.
I want my data to look like this:

```
#>   fruits remove_strings   new_fruits
#>   <chr>           <dbl>
#> 1 apple               1      pple
#> 2 banana              4        na
#> 3 ananas              2       anas
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `substr`:

```r
with(df, substr(fruits, remove_strings + 1, nchar(fruits)))
# [1] "pple" "na"   "anas"
```

Or, using `str_sub`:

```r
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(removed = str_sub(fruits, remove_strings + 1))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  fruits remove_strings removed
  <chr>           <dbl> <chr>  
1 apple               1 pple   
2 banana              4 na     
3 ananas              2 anas
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df$new_fruits = substring(df$fruits, df$remove_strings + 1)
[1] "pple" "na"   "ana
```

Answer (score 0):

```
substr(fruits, remove_strings+1, nchar(fruits))
```

(I would like to say that I solved the problem independently of Maëls solution. I cannot prove that but it's the first time that this happens in any of my posts.)